# Virtual Functions Polymorphism and Inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, virtual

I know the title sucks... but I have no clue what actual issue I have got at my hands...

I have defined a base class for linked lists and a specialized class that inherits the base class.

Base:

list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <string>
#include "../../declarations.h"
#include "element.h"

class List: public Element{
/*
 * @brief is a generic list class, designed to be inherited by more
 * specialised list emulating classes.
 */

    public: // methods

        /// generates empty list.
        List(){
            init();
            cout << "defining List" << endl;
        }

        /// Removes first list element
        bool remove_first(){

            if (!is_empty()){
                Element* newFirst = first;
                delete first;
                first = newFirst->next;
                return true;
            }
            else{
                std::cerr << "list already empty" << endl;
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// removes last list element
        bool remove_last(){

            // store length fo list in min_len for switch
            unsigned int min_len = 0;
            if (!is_empty()){
                if ((first->next) != 0){
                    min_len = 2;
                }
                else {
                    min_len = 1;
                }
            }
            // as switch doesn't allow for comparisons, map any value greater
            // 1 to 2       if (min_len>1) min_len = 2;
            switch (min_len){
                case (2):{
                    // Iterate over list, always look two elements ahead.
                    // If the next element points to 0 you have found your new last
                    // element (the current next to last one). Delete current-> next
                    // to remove the last element and let the new last one point to
                    // zero.
                    Element* current = first;
                    while((current->next)->next != 0){
                        current = (current->next);
                    }
                    delete (current->next);
                    current->next = 0;
                    return true;
                }
                // if the list contaisn only one element use remove_first()
                // as the logic for that case is already present there
                case (1): return remove_first();
                case (0):{
                    std::cerr << "list already empty" << endl;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Declare several virtual functions for appending elements
        // that get defined in the iheriting classes.
        virtual void append_front(int i){};
        virtual void append_front(char c){};
        virtual void append_front(std::string s){};

        virtual void append_back(int i){};
        virtual void append_back(char c){};
        virtual void append_back(std::string s){};


        /// todo
        std::string head(){}

        /// returns length of list
        unsigned length(){

            unsigned counter = 0;
            Element* current = first;

            while(current != 0) {
                ++counter;
                current = current->next;
            }
            return counter;
        }

        /// determines whether list is empty
        bool is_empty(){
            return first == 0;
        }

        // printing depends on type of list, so this method gets defined in
        // inheriting class
        virtual void print(){};


    private: // methods

        void init(){
            // initialise empty list with a NULL pointer
            first = 0;
        }

    protected: // data members

        /// points to first list element or zero, if list is empty
        Element* first;
};

#endif
```

Derived:

transitionsList.h

```
#ifndef TRANSITION_LIST_H
#define TRANSITION_LIST_H

#include "../../../generic/list.h"
#include "../../elements/transition/transition.h"

class TransitionList: public List {

    public:

        void append_front(char c){

            // generate list element and store in pointer e
            Element* e;
            e = new Transition();
            // store parameter c in the object *e points to
            e->set_content(c);
            // Either list is empty. In thet case object at &e becomes first
            // list element and also the last.
            // Or list wasn't empty and e->next points to the current first, then
            // object *e points to becomes first.
            if (is_empty()) {
                first = e;
                e->next = 0;
            }
            else {
                e->next = first;
                first = e;
            }
        }


        void append_back(char c){

            if (is_empty()) {
                append_front(c);
            }
            else {
                Element* e;
                e = new Transition();
                e->set_content(c);
                e->next = 0;
                // Go through the list until you find the last element, let it
                // then ppint to the new last element.
                Element* current = first;
                while(current->next != 0) {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                current->next = e;
            }
        }


        void print(){

            cout << "[";
            // go through the list, starting with first element
            Element* current = first;
            // as long as the last list element is not the current one, keep
            // printing elements.
            while (current != 0) {
                cout << " " << current->get_content();
                // let current be the next of current current, to move
                // through the list
                current = current->next;
            } // while
            cout << " ]";
        }
};

#endif
```

These two depend on a few other classes:

element.h:

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include "../../declarations.h"


class State;

class Element{
/*
 * @brief is a generic list element class, designed to be inherited by
 *  more specialised list element classes.
 */
    public:

        Element(){}

        virtual ~Element(){}

        virtual void set_content(int i){};
        virtual void set_content(char c){};
        virtual void set_content(std::string s){};

        virtual char get_content() = 0;


        Element* next;  ///< is the pointer to the next transition in the list

};

#endif
```

state.h:

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

#include "../../declarations.h"

class List;

class State{
/**
 * @brief is a class emulating a trie state
 */

    public: // methods

        State(){
            cout << "defining State" << endl;
            init();
        }

    private: // methods

        void init(){

        }

    private: // variables

        // Pointer required due to forward declarations
        List* transitions; ///< is the list of states dominated by THIS.
        // count stores how often the word the current path codes for has been
        // found in the training data.
        int count; ///< is the number of occurances of some word in this path.

};

#endif
```

and transition.h

```
#ifndef TRANSITION_H
#define TRANSITION_H

#include "../../../generic/element.h"
#include "../../state.h"

typedef char cont;

class Transition: public Element {
public:

    void set_content(cont c){
        content = c;
    };

    cont get_content(){
        return content;
        };

    State* successor;
    Transition* next;  ///< is the pointer to the next transition in the list

protected:

    cont content; ///< is the character this transition codes for

};

#endif
```

When I now run this cpp-file:

list_test.cpp:

```
#include "transitionList.h"

int main(){
    TransitionList* derivedList;
    List *baseList = &derivedList;
}
```

I get the error:

```
list_test2.cpp:5:8: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'List *' with an rvalue of type 'TransitionList **'
```

Which I don't understand, because I am under the (apparently phony) impression, that this would be analogous to what I saw in this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/DudHooleNVg?t=4m59s

Where is

```
int main(){
        TransitionList* derivedList;
        List *baseList = &derivedList;
}
```

not analogous to

```
int main(){
        Ninja* n;
        Enemy *enemy1 = &n;
}
```

:/ Very confused.

Comment: Try removing the "&" from the line where you are asigning value to your baseList in your main. You are asigning to a pointer to List type a pointer to pointer to List type.

Comment: The code is too big to read and understand. But, `List *baseList = &derivedList;` is wrong. You did not allocate memory for derivedList and then once you do that, `List* baseList = derivedList;` is fine.

Comment: Read the error message again, it really tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: Apart from that inheriting `List` from `Element` is wrong IMO, `List` contains elements does not have to inherit them.

Comment: I also have some nitpicking with the inheritance chain you have. A list isn't really an element in the list. A list *contains* elements, but it *isn't* an element.

Comment: following your definition of "class TransitionList: public List", TransitionList* and List* show the same level of indirection, meaning that List* baseList = derivedList; should work where assigning a pointer to a pointer to a list is correctly reported as an error. I didn't look at the tutorial though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works. But I have not quite grasped why yet and am still confused about the difference between my construction and the one in the tutorial.
I guess the answer to that lies in what wonko said... but I don't really understand it yet.

Oh, and you are right about inheriting Element... that does indeed not make a whole lot of sense. I changed that.

Comment: Unrelated: `Element* newFirst = first;  delete first; first = newFirst->next;` Think long and hard about that sequence of code and ask yourself, "What does `newFirst` point to when I dereference it?" The phrase "Now it works" hardly applies to that code. It invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes should be Element* oldFirst = first; first = first->next; delete oldFirst;

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say it . Your list is bad [but] you should[n't] feel bad. Why the heck are you writing your own container ? You are making your life miserable. use `std::list` or better yet `std::vector`. Be happy. the world is ugly enough as it is without a 12millionth bad implementation of  list. While you are at it throw away all the `*`. You are not a ninja yet. Use values wherever possible.